# returning OkNegotiatedContentResult does not do content nogotiation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In ASP.NET Web API (4.6.2) why wrapping response inside `Ok` does not do content negotiation?

For example
Http Request has the following headers:

```
 Content-Type:application/json and 
 Accept:application/xml
```

and i have two methods

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetData()
    {
        return Ok(new { FirstName = "foo", LastName = "bar" });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public Person GetData2()
    {
        return new Person { FirstName = "foo", LastName = "bar" };
    }
```

The first method always returns response in `Json` format. It does not obey the `Accept` header. The return type of the `Ok` method is `OkNegotiatedContentResult`. Which as per the documentation

> Represents an action result that performs content negotiation and
>   returns an HttpStatusCode.OK response when it succeeds

Second method `GetData2`, however, returns the correct response and obey the `Accept` header

**Update 1**
looks like `Ok` does not do content-negotiation with anonymous types.
if i do

```
 return Ok( new Person(){FirstName="foo", LastName="bar"});
```

it works